# Determine historical UTC offset given lat, long, date

Tags: .net, timezone, nodatime

Some locations change have changed timezones (& UTC offset) over time - Louisville, KY in 1949 was in CST (-6) but is currently EDT (-4):
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/louisville?year=1945

Most lat/long libraries will return the current timezone, but I need to determine the historical timezone & utc offset, given lat/long and UTC date.

Does nodatime (which includes the Tzdb Olson historical data) have this functionality or maybe in combination with another library?

Comment: or given lat,long,local date-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this combining [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org) and [GeoTimeZone](https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone).

```
using GeoTimeZone;
using NodaTime;

...

static Offset GetOffset(Instant instant, double lat, double lon)
{
    string tzid = TimeZoneLookup.GetTimeZone(lat, lon).Result;
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[tzid];
    return tz.GetUtcOffset(instant);
}
```

Using your example:

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromUtc(1945, 12, 31, 0, 0);
Offset offset = GetOffset(instant, 38.2527, -85.7585);  // Louisville, KY, USA

Console.WriteLine(offset);  // -06
```

Keep in mind that the result is only as good as the data.  The IANA tzdb doesn't guarantee accuracy for dates before 1970.